# How to get number of items in ObservableCollection from XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, observablecollection

I'm displaying all of my customers which I get from a ViewModel ObservableCollectoin property within a ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerComboBoxTemplate}"
    Margin="20"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Is there a way to get the number of items in the ObservableCollection **without creating another ViewModel property**, e.g. something like this:

**PSEUDO-CODE:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Customers.Count()}"/>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ObservableCollection type exposes a Count Property which you can use. 
I don't know if ObservableCollection raises the PropertyChanged event in order to inform the UI about updates to this property though.

Comment: ok it's just this: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Customers.Count}"/>, and yes it seems to constantly update when the ObservableCollection changes, nice.